# Loading styles with @media

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

If I'm typed:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="small.css" />
```

Or

```
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
      // Import code
}
```

On screens <600px styles don't apply, but css file will be downloaded or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Chrome Network inspector, **yes**, the file will still be downloaded.

Here's my test setup :

```
- index.php
- css
   - main.css 
   - light.css
```

My HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/light.css" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.css` is empty and `light.css` contains this :

```
body{background-color: blue;}
```

Regardless of the window size, this is what the Network inspector shows :

[image]

The background is only blue when the page is over 600px.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS file will always be downloaded regardless of the `media` value you set.

The only time the CSS file will actually be used is if the statement within the `media` is true.

As a demo, below loads in 2 CSS files which don't actually exist and will therefore error within the browser's console log. The `media` will fail but the file will still try to download the file.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 10000px)" href="small.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normal.css" />
```

You can find out more about CSS media queries with the below links:

- [Media Queries - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0)
- [Using media queries - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="small.css" />
```

The external HTTP request will still be there no matter what the viewport if that's what you're asking? The only thing that won't happen is the styles themselves won't take effect if the viewport is below 600px.

Why don't you try using the Chrome emulator and inspecting the page on the Network tab at a viewport below 600px and reloading a page where you've got this request and see if it indeed requests it with a status of 200 (OK).